# To set adjustable row-height in mat-grid-list

Tags: angular, angular6

I am defining 3 columns using  `mat-grid-list` like this.

**HTML**

```
<mat-grid-list [cols]="breakpoint" rowHeight="200px" 
       (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
       <mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>
       <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
       <mat-grid-tile>3</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Here i have set row height to 200px (**rowHeight="200px"**), Now height of each row is same as shown in below image.

[image]

But i need to set height of the row according the content present inside it.As shown in below image.

[image]

How can i achieve this? Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-mat-grid-cu7zzp?file=app%2Fdemo%2Fdemo.component.html) link.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and it seems that angular material grid does not support this which is really strange, so I used css grid instead. They really do not provide this functionality, altough it might be possible to css hack it, but then it has no point using material grid in this case.

Comment: Is it possible to set different height for each ` mat-grid-tile`??